# Why is there a san in 照れ屋さん?

Tags: words

照れ屋さん means "a shy person", but I don't understand why there's a さん. 
When I googled it I saw the usage of さん was nearly universal, but Google didn't say why.

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14618/1628 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16049/1628

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "お寿司屋さん" personification?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16049/is-%e3%81%8a%e5%af%bf%e5%8f%b8%e5%b1%8b%e3%81%95%e3%82%93-personification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "name is shy"? 照れ屋さん means "a shy person" as a whole.

屋 is a suffix with [various meanings](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%B1%8B), one of which is "person who tends to do ～" or simply "-er". Examples:

- 照れ屋: a shy person
- 頑張り屋: a hard worker
- 寂しがり屋: someone who gets lonely easily; someone who cannot stand alone
- 気取り屋: a smug person
- 分からず屋: a stubborn/hardheaded person

This -さん has little to do with the meaning, but it is making the ～屋 word sound more friendly and/or prettier. Please see the links in the comment section. (It's not usually used with derogatory words like 気取り屋.)

Comment: I don't understand why for example " Naruto-chan is a shy person" needs to be made friendlier and prettier?

Why this adjective and not others?

Comment: @Can'tRead English also has suffixes used solely to make a word sound "cute". For example "-ie" as in "doggie" is an example (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diminutives_by_language#English)). 君は照れ屋だね may sound a little negative, but 君は照れ屋さんだね sounds friendlier and gentler.